# Which visa is required to visit my employer in Canada?

Tags: visas, canada, german-citizens, j1-visas

I am German and I have a German passport.

I'll be doing an internship in the US with a J1 visa.

Now I'll have the opportunity to visit the company office in Canada.

Will I need a Visa for this and if yes which one?

Comment: As a German citizen, you do not need a visa for a business visit to Canada, but you do need authorization to *work* in Canada.  I suspect that this qualifies as a business visit, and therefore does not require work authorization, but whether that is true probably depends on what you will be doing at the company office in Canada.  Can you edit your question to include a few words about that?

Comment: Also note that if you enter as a visitor without a visa, you will need to get an eTA before boarding the flight if you are arriving in Canada by air, but you will not need anything if you are arriving in Canada by land or sea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a visa for your visit to Canada : 
Check this link : https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/entry-requirements-country.html
You have : 6 months and the eTA is required if arriving by air.

Here is more information about the eTA if you need one : https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/eta/apply.html